# Converting XML file elements into a PHP array

Tags: php, xml, steam

I'm trying to convert a Steam group members list XML file into an array by using Php.
The XML file is: http://steamcommunity.com/groups/starhawk/memberslistxml/?xml=1.xml

The elements are the member's steam IDs, such as 76561198000264284

How can I go about doing this?

Edit: So far I've used something like this:

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode((array)simplexml_load_string($xml)),1);
```

It outputs the first few elements, not ones specifically
from

Comment: [`SimpleXML`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) would be a good start.

Comment: $array = json_decode(json_encode((array)simplexml_load_string($xml)),1);
I've tried something like this, only it outputs the first few elements, not ones specifically from <members>

Comment: you are doing too much :) just use the simplexmlelement and access the value you're interested in. there is not much use to mangle it through array conversions, it works much better without.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This should return the fully accessible array:

```
$get = file_get_contents('http://steamcommunity.com/groups/starhawk/memberslistxml/?xml=1.xml');
$arr = simplexml_load_string($get);
print_r($arr);
```

You can now access items like this:

```
echo $arr->groupID64;
echo $arr->members->steamID64;
```

Edit:
To parse the streamID, you can do a for loop

```
$ids = $arr->members->steamID64;
foreach($ids as $id) {
    echo $id;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I only want it to output the SteamID64s from the <members> element.

Answer (score 1):

you can use below functional code to get your correct answer

```
<?php
$getfile = file_get_contents('http://steamcommunity.com/groups/starhawk/memberslistxml/?xml=1.xml');

$arr = simplexml_load_string($getfile);

foreach($arr->members->steamID64 as $a => $b) {
    echo "<br>".$a,'="',$b,"\"\n";
}
?>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
steamID64="76561198009904532" 
steamID64="76561198004808757" 
steamID64="76561198000264284" 
steamID64="76561198016710420" 
steamID64="76561198005429187" 
steamID64="76561198030184436" 
steamID64="76561197980763372" 
steamID64="76561197972363016" 
steamID64="76561198045469666" 
steamID64="76561198010892015" 
steamID64="76561198028438913" 
steamID64="76561197967117636" 
steamID64="76561197980283206" 
steamID64="76561197992198727" 
steamID64="76561198018960482" 
steamID64="76561198071675315" 
steamID64="76561198010447988" 
steamID64="76561198025628761"
```

if you wish to customize you can make it as per your need. let me know if i can help you more..